# Is torch Conv2d filter random? Can I see the kernel shape?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm studying pytorch Conv2d package, for convolution filter.
I coded like below, to check what the Conv2d function exactly do to image.
And I found that the image filtered by conv2d looks different at every try, randomly. Just like the picture attached. So I've got questions like this.

- Is the kernel of Conv2d changes randomly for each trying? why?
- Can I see the shape of kernel inside the conv2d?

below is the code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

img = cv2.imread('data/dog.jpg') # 29 *30 *3

data = asarray(img) 

conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,1,3)


pyplot.subplot(1,2,2)
data = np.transpose(data, (2,0,1))
data = conv1(torch.Tensor(data))
data = np.transpose(data.detach().numpy(), (1,2,0))
pyplot.imshow(data, cmap='gray')
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is called [Reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html)

Just add the following code and it will work with the same weights every time.

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
```

Everytime you initialize `Conv2D` layer, it is initialized with random weights. But setting PyTorch's `manual_seed` to a constant number generates the same sequence of random numbers every time you run your code. This is what ***Reproducibility*** aims for. You can check [PyTorch's reproducibility reference](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) for more information regarding that topic.

**TQCH**'s code helps you check out the weights every time you run your code. You will notice that the weights change every time you run `print(conv1.weight)`. And you will also notice that they do not change every time you run the code if you specify the manual seed

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create a `Conv2d` object, the weights are randomly initialized. That's why you would see different results. To inpect the shape of the kernel, run

```
print(conv1.weight.shape)
```